# Can I configure XFCE terminal the way to open all the new terminals as tabs of one window?

Tags: terminal, configuration, xfce

I strongly prefer to have one terminal window with all the terminals being tabs in it, but the most usual way I open a terminal is calling it from another application (usually with "Open Terminal Here" option in Thunar).

Can it be configured so that whenever XFCE terminal is being called, it would open a new tab in the existing window instead of a new window?

Comment: If you're using a terminal multiplexer such as tmux, you could send it a message to open a new window.  The xfce context menu should be editable to do so.. somehow..

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to direct an existing Terminal process to open a tab in a given directory.